# Chung Elementary probability theory pp. 230-231 - Normal distribution

Tags: probability

> $$
> \Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^x_{-\infty}e^{-u^2/2}\,du\text{,}\qquad\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\text{.}
> $$

> Next, $\varphi$ has derivatives of all orders, and each derivative is the product of $\varphi$ by a polynomial called a Hermite polynomial. The existence of all derivatives makes the curve $x\rightarrow\varphi(x)$ very smooth, and it is usually describes as "bell-shaped". Furthermore as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, $\varphi(x)$ decreases to $0$ very rapidly. The following estimate of the tail of $\Phi$ is often useful:
> $$
> 1-\Phi(x)=\int^\infty_x\varphi(u)\,du\leq\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}x}\text{,}\quad x>0\text{.}
> $$
> It follows that not only $\Phi$ has moments of all orders, but even the integral
> $$\tag{7.4.3}
> M(\theta)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{\theta x}\phi(x)\,dx=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\exp\left(\theta x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,dx
> $$
> is finite for every real $\theta$, because $e^{-x^2/2}$ decreases much faster than $e^{|\theta x|}$ increases as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.

I want to ask the last sentence. It follows from what? I know how to prove that by the Cauchy Criterion, but I want to know what the author means.

Comment: The intuition is that the term $\theta x$ is insignificant against $-x^2/2$ when x is large. In other words, this integral behaves as $\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2/2}dx$, ie, is convergent

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral into integrals over $|x| \geq 4|\theta|$ and $|x| <4 |\theta|$. In the first part use the fact that $\theta x \leq \frac {x^{2}} 4$ so $\theta x -\frac {x^{2}} 2 \leq -\frac {x^{2}} 4$. [ Also, $e^{-\frac {x^{2}}4}$ is integrable]. Second part is easy to handle since a bounded  continuous function is integrable over a finite interval.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int\exp\left(\theta x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx=\int \exp(\theta x)\exp(-x^2/2)dx\\=\int{\exp{\theta x}\over\exp{x^2/2}}dx
$$
If $x\gg \theta$, $\exp x^2/2\gg \exp \theta x$.

Another way to see this is to complete the square.
$$
\int \exp(\theta x- x^2/2)dx=\int \exp(-(x-\theta)^2/2+\theta^2/4)dx\\
=\exp(\theta^2/4)\times\int\exp(-x'^2/2)dx'
$$
where $x'=x-\theta$.